# What are ASP.NET Core Static Web Assets?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor

There is a lot of hidden magic that occurs in `HostBuilder.ConfigureWebHostDefaults()` (that eventually calls [`ConfigureWebDefaults`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/1480b998660d2f77d0605376eefab6a83474ce07/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebHost.cs#L208)). I would like to understand it better as there is no documentation that I can find about it.

[This code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/1480b998660d2f77d0605376eefab6a83474ce07/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebHost.cs#L210) seems to be loading some static files. What are static web assets and why do we need them? Is this something to do with embedding static assets into libraries for Blazor?

```cs
builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, cb) =>
{
    if (ctx.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets(ctx.HostingEnvironment, ctx.Configuration);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is related to Blazor only, but to web hosting in general: mvc app, Razor Pages apps and Blazor apps.  I guess that static web assets are objects like JavaScript files, style sheets, and images, etc.

Comment: Just curious, but did you [inspect that class's source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/1480b998660d2f77d0605376eefab6a83474ce07/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/StaticWebAssets/StaticWebAssetsLoader.cs) to see what it is doing?

Comment: Static assets are objects you send to the user that the server does not change. Images are an example of static assets. The shown code is simply checking for configuration on where to look for static assets.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Static Web Assets are static files made available from a [Razor Class Library (RCL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class):

> An RCL may require companion static assets that can be referenced by the consuming app of the RCL. ASP.NET Core allows creating RCLs that include static assets that are available to a consuming app.

`UseStaticWebAssets` inserts additional [file providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers) (instances of [`StaticWebAssetsFileProvider`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/1480b998660d2f77d0605376eefab6a83474ce07/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/StaticWebAssets/StaticWebAssetsFileProvider.cs#L24)), using a manifest file (`{environment.ApplicationName}.StaticWebAssets.xml` if not set via `IConfiguration`) to determine a list of mappings from path to base path.

As an example, when using the ASP.NET Core Identity UI RCL, the manifest file for your app looks something like this:

```xml
<StaticWebAssets Version="1.0">
    <ContentRoot BasePath="/Identity" Path="\path\to\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ui\3.0.0\staticwebassets\V4" />
</StaticWebAssets>
```

This all ends up with a [`CompositeFileProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.0#compositefileprovider) being set for the [`IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootFileProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment.webrootfileprovider). This composite provider does two things:

1. Processes the `wwwroot/` static files as usual (assuming default configuration).
2. Delegates any files requested from `wwwroot/Identity` to the extracted NuGet package content folder for the Identity UI.

As the code snippet from your question shows, this only happens when running in the `Development` environment. When your app is *published*, the files in question get copied up into the `wwwroot` folder, as though they were part of your app.

Comment: Thank you, @kirk-larkin, for this brilliant answer. Would you clarify how, as stated in your last paragraph, when the app is published _the files in question get copied up into the `wwwroot` folder_? I have an environment named 'Test' and this magic isn't happening; what would I need to set/do to make it work for Test (other than manually calling `StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets()`, that is)?