# Identity project updated to Asp.Net Core 3 gives wwwroot folder

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an asp.net core 2.2.6 web api project. No views, no script files, no css nothing. I just upgraded it to asp.net core 3.1 and when I publish using release build I see a wwwroot folder containing css,js and lib folders containing css and js files.

How can I remove them since I don't see them anywhere in my solution?
Here is the code for adding identity:

Update #1

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
}).AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
.AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

// Set expiration time for confirmation links 
services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
{
    options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(confirmationLinksExpirationInMinutes);
});

JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear(); 
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

})
.AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
{
    cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    cfg.SaveToken = true;
    cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtBearerSettings:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtBearerSettings:Issuer"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtBearerSettings:SecurityKey"])),
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero 
    };
});
```

Update #2

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="4.9.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore" Version="3.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0-rc4" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="5.6.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="log4net.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the autogenerated files come from `AddDefaultIdentity`.

When using `AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bookstrap4)`, ASP.NET Core automatically uses views for all of the identity views (I think there are 28 of them) but they are hidden from the solution. You can manually include and modify them by [scaffolding identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio). However, when you delete these views, they are not removed but rather autogenerated and hidden again.

I guess that the created CSS and JS files are autogenerated for these auto-generated views.

You can change you call to add identity to avoid this by using

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
.AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Depending on whether you are using .NET Core 2.2 or .NET Core 3.1, you might need to add an additional NuGet package. (Not sure if my memory is correct: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` v2.2.0 and v3.1.0 behave differently. You might need to add https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/ when using v3.1.0)

Comment: My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58436497/what-are-asp-net-core-static-web-assets/58485311#58485311) _might_ help a little with the specifics. Identity was switched over to use Static Web Assets for 3.0.

Comment: @citronas. I changed the code as you suggested but still the same output

Comment: @KirkLarkin Is there any way to remove these files?

Comment: I dont want them at all there. I developed my own spa logic with views etc.. so there is no purpose of having them there.

Comment: Found workaround here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16862

Answer (score 0):

That is the new method with Core 3.0+  All scripts, script libraries etc go in  wwwroot folder

I used to keep all of these scripts in  ~/Area/AreaName/scripts  but core 3.0 will not read them out of that dir.

it is something to do with security and stopping people from being able to access those files.