# Blazor CSS file is not served in .NET 8 preview 6 with the new project template

Tags: css, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a started a new Blazor project for .NET 8 preview 6.

On the main index page, I have written the following code adding an optional parameter:

```
@page "/{optional?}"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Home</h1>

Welcome to your new app.
@Optional

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Optional { get; set; }
}
```

Problem now is that on localhost the bundled CSS file is considered a parameter on `GET` request and the page has no style added.

```
localhost/ProjectName.styles.css
```

here `ProjectName.styles.css` is considered on `GET` request when browser tries to fetch the stylesheet a string.

How can I move the generated CSS file to a subfolder?

Is there anyway to solve this problem without changing the code in `Index.razor` ?

Comment: Couldn't you just use something like `@page "/list/{optional?}"` or `@page "/home/{optional?}"` to avoid that issue? Give the "page URL" some fixed part that makes it clear it's not the CSS being loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced your issue:

[image]

> Blazor CSS file is not served in .NET 8 preview 6

If you input the uri`localhost/ProjectName.styles.css` in address bar,it would go to your index page not the css file

If you comment this line :

```
app.MapRazorComponents<App>();
```

and try with the uri again,you would receive the css file

accroding to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#css-isolation-bundling):

> CSS isolation occurs at build time. Blazor rewrites CSS selectors to
> match markup rendered by the component. The rewritten CSS styles are
> bundled and produced as a static asset.
> and this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58436497/what-are-asp-net-core-static-web-assets) related

it makes no sense to determine where the static asset locates,but you could  modify the request path to your staticfiles to avoid the confliction(If you want to keep the codes in Index page)

```
app.UseStaticFiles("/MyStaticFiles");
```

And modify the links in your `app.razor`:

```
.....
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MyStaticFiles/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MyStaticFiles/css/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MyStaticFiles/css/app.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MyStaticFiles/BlazorApp2.styles.css" />
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>
......
```

Now it works :
[image]