# Razor application 404 page not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

When I start a .Net 5 Razor application with

```
dotnet BaGet.dll
```

It always says 404 page not found.

[image]

However if I dotnet run it or execute the BaGet.exe file, everything are fine.

All these static files are seperated in another project

[image]

https://github.com/loic-sharma/BaGet

```
var path = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "..", "BaGet.Web");
```

The ContentRootPath is correct that

```
var provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.GetFullPath(path))
```

Is verified nornal...

How do I use correctly do "dotnet BaGet.dll"?

Comment: Could you kindly check the solution below? If you need further help, please let me know.

Comment: Let me check it today!! Thanks! One info of me, I was using .net 5.0, Does that matter?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the .Net version. You can check whether there are those js and css files in the wwwroot folder.

Comment: After I tried this, it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[static-web-assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58436497/what-are-asp-net-core-static-web-assets)

The final answer is that to publish application and UseStaticFiles works.

Answer (score 0):

It's a expected behavior. [There is not any static files under wwwroot folder](https://github.com/loic-sharma/BaGet/tree/main/src/BaGet/wwwroot).

Finally, I find all the files [here](https://github.com/loic-sharma/BaGet/releases/download/v0.4.0-preview2/BaGet.zip).

[image]

Then copy them into `wwwroot` folder inside the project, like below.

[image]

And add below settings in .csproj file which will include the static files when build the project.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Then we will find the `wwwroot` folder under the `YOUR_DRIVER:\BaGet-main\BaGet-main\src\BaGet\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1`.

[image]

#### OK, now you can run the command to start the project.

[image]